# Why does textview with weight have invalid height in case of text wrapping?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-xml, android-wrap-content

I have a dialog, which has a layout xml. Controls are vertically aligned, and in one "row" there is a textview and a seekbar. Textview has `weight=1`, and seekbar has `weight=2`.

Now the problem is that if textview cannot fit, it is wrapped, but the height of the textview is not adjusted, and the second line is not visible.

Layout xml:

```xml
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

  <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/dialog_settings_layout_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="240dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    ....other controls.....

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/dialog_settings_layout_volume"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_dialog_settings"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="aaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbb cccccccccc"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar_dialog_settings"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:max="8"
        android:progress="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    ....other controls.....
```

[image]

Comment: You have to show what is around LinearLayout because probably there is a problem.

Comment: Remove this line and check `android:layout_weight="1"` its working fine if you use `LinearLayout`

Comment: The parent LinearLayout height is not adjusted on the TextView height change. Quick fix: make the TextView single line (also reduce its textSize a bit).

Comment: em surprised, how this works android:layout_width="0px" ? :P

Comment: @Loop: I edited the layout XML to see what is around the LinerLayout

Comment: @Frank N. Stein: I don't want to reduce the testSize, and if it's single line the text will not fit

Comment: If you use layout_weight in horizontal layout then layout_width is not used. Setting to 0dp is an optimisation.

Comment: Is vertical LinearLayout containing only other horizontal LinearLayouts?

Comment: So, try to force the TextView lines to 2.

Comment: @Loop: yes, the outmost vertical LinearLayout contains several controls and Horizontal LinearLayouts, similar to the above one.

Comment: @Frank N. Stein: I do not use hardcoded line numbers, as for different languages it could be 1-2-3 lines.

Comment: You **should**. So the TextView won't change its height. `android:lines="3"` should do the trick. Just make the TextView gravity vertically centered.

Comment: That's not good, as if the text on X language occupies 1 line only, it looks very ugly, 3 lines of space if used for 1 line of text.

Comment: Do you have layout_weight specified for children of vertical LinearLayout? I just created simple example with similar layout and setting parameters you showed and it works fine. So there must be something with layout parts that are not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I have solution.

Set **match_parent** for `ScrollView` width and height and horizontal `LinearLayout` width.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/dialog_settings_layout_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="240dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

I have tried to reproduce it and everything worked till I wrapped layout with ScrollView which I missed at the beginning. Then I had exactly the same problem, adjusting mentioned values solved it.

**Update**

To make it work inside Dialog, create one using `AlertDialog.Builder`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
builder.setView(view);
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

dialog.show();
```

Comment: I changed the XML, and in Eclipse/Graphical Layout it displayed correctly. Hurray! But then I tried on my device, and it still not ok. Please note, this layout is used in a dialog, not in an activity. Code:
`final Dialog dialogSettings = new Dialog(this);`    `dialogSettings.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` `dialogSettings.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_settings);` 
`...`
`((TextView)dialogSettings.findViewById(R.id.textView_dialog_settings)).setText(....)`
`dialogSettings.show();`

Also! Maybe  that could be the problem? The textview text is changed after setContentView.

Comment: No, I removed the `setText()` after the `setContentView` to just use something from the XML, but still the same on the device/dialog. Probably then the Dialog ruins it?

Comment: Creating dialogs the way you do is not recommended. Read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html. I have used AlertDialog.Builder and it works now like a charm. Even more preferable is using DialogFragment.

Comment: I replaced the Dialog with AlertDialog, and now it appears just as I wanted. Thanks